# Servlet. How do I access external directory from my url?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am currently developing a social network site using Java in which whenever a user registers, a new directory is created for them in an external location (Desktop/users/username).

Now I want to be able to access that folder directly by typing it into my url(http://localhost:8080/Website/users/username).

How do I achieve that? Or should I just place the users directory in the WebContent folder?

Comment: Select a path in the URL for folder access, e.g. `/Website/users/*`, and map that to a servlet which will process all such requests.  Inside that servlet, you can access the user data on the server side and do your business.  Of course, a nicer way of doing this would be to use something like Restlets or Spring MVC.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_page_redirect.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Servlet` mapped to url `/Website/users/{userId}` you can through Java API access files on filesystem and generate an HTML page which is returned to the back the user.

Comment: After much research, I finally found a way to do it.
I created a servlet with url pattern = " /users/* "
then I used `request.getRequestDispatcher(<jsp page>).include(request, response);` to include the jsp page in the servlet